# MySQL db from uninstalled XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have done something stupid: I have started uninstalling XAMPP without exporting the DB. Realising what I had done during uninstallation, I told the installer not to delete the databases. Now I have a mysql folder with the data, but no MySQL program to handle it.

What do I do with it now? Can I simply copy it to another installation? I guess not, so what shall I do?

I tried searching the web for this, but did not find anything useful. There must be a reason for the uninstaller asking this, so how do I do it?

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652949/what-is-the-exact-location-of-mysql-database-tables-in-xampp-folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using xamp I once copied the all files from 
`mysql\mysql5.5.16\data\`
to same directory my other computer. and was surprised to see it work.
but there must be some condition about same version or datadir settings.

Comment: It worked for a different version - though the root user could no longer log in. Different users could, so I could export the data.

Answer (score 1):

Check your backup folder for the existence of .frm .MYI & .MYD files if the backup contains these files just install the same version of mysql and copy those files to your data folder it worked for me. May be you too.