# how to restore databases in phpmyadmin after uninstallation of xampp

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

As my XAMPP was not working properly, I have uninstalled it from my computer. While installation, I got the warning message about whether I want to delete the htdocs folder too. As all my programs were in htdocs, I have not deleted it. But I got no warning message about the databases and as a result I have forgotten about the databases. I have no backup copy too. After uninstallation, I found that xampp contains only the folder htdocs and no databases. Is there anyway to restore the  databases? Please help. I am very anxious as there were a lot of data and tables in the databases.

Comment: I doubt there is a way !

Comment: sorry to say that there is no way.you can try to restore folder by file recovery applications

Answer (score 4):

According to [What is the exact location of Mysql database tables in XAMPP folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652949/what-is-the-exact-location-of-mysql-database-tables-in-xampp-folder), XAMPP stores the MySQL datadir in `C:\xampp\mysql\data` on Windows and `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql` on Mac. Unless you manually changed the datadir, your database files are stored in the XAMPP folder. Since that folder only has the `htdocs` subdirectory now, unfortunately, your database seems to be gone. If you have file-level backups of the old system, there's a chance you can restore the database enough to recover the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore old mysql\data\ to new installed xamp, your newly installed xamp version must be same as old xamp version.

Then only restore data will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you restore old mysql\data\ to new installed xamp, your newly installed xamp version must be same as old xamp version,
but that can not restore the data in your databases
it only returns the database and tables space only.
so be sorry!