# Does Removing Xampp Mean Deleting Databases

Tags: php, apache, xampp

But now my question is that, if I unistall XAMPP from my computer, will I lose the databases that I've had or not ?

If yes, then how can I backup the data in PHPMYADMIN ?

Comment: If you are not sure about the databases, just make their backup and reinstall it. If the db are gone then put them back. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35895901/6468413

Answer (score 3):

may be they asked for backup of htdocs and mysql folder when you uninstall the xampp I am not sure so take backup of all your data base first as sql or text file

option 1:-
you can also take backup from xampp\mysql\data\ on this location you find folder for each database that will also help to restore your database

option 2:-
but the safest way is backup your database as (sql or text file).once you ensure with backup as text or sql file you also try option 1 for learning

Answer (score 2):

As you can see here https://support.managed.com/kb/a2034/how-to-backup-and-or-restore-your-mysql-database-using-phpmyadmin.aspx

To backup your database

1. Log into your cPanel
2. On the Home screen, scroll down to Databases and click on phpMyAdmin.
3. Select the database you would like to backup from the left navigation tree.
4. Click the Export tab.
5. Choose the Quick export method and click Go.

To restore

1. Choose the database you want to restore from the left navigation tree.
2. The phpMyAdmin script that restores your database does not drop the tables first. Click the Check All check box.
3. Click the With selected: drop down menu and choose Drop.
4. Confirm by clicking Yes.
5. Click the Import tab.
6. Click the Choose File button to browse for the MySQL backup.
7. Click Go.

I like using the workbench. give it a try
https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).