# Where is the database which is created in localhost server stored in computer/pc/local directory in xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have created several databases in xampp server, now my xampp is not working. I want to back up those databases. I have not yet unistalled the xampp but i want to uninstall it for reinstalling. I need to know where the databases are stored in my pc drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the exact location of MySQL database tables in XAMPP folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652949/what-is-the-exact-location-of-mysql-database-tables-in-xampp-folder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where does MySQL store database files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091350/where-does-mysql-store-database-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your database is in this directory C:\xampp\mysql\data

Answer (score 3):

Use this command in mySQL:

```
mysql> select @@datadir;
```